# HTML5 Ipad Error while downloading large numbers of pictures

Tags: ipad, html, storage, offline

I want to develop an offline html5 website with a large number of pictures (10 000).
The problem is that during the downloading process when safari ask me to increase the cache limit it stop the download and i need to start it again.
It's possible to make such application in html5 on a ipad ? can we breach the offline cach limit :) ?
Thks a lot in advance !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The limit is set inside the browser itself, typically at 5MB. Currently, as far as I'm aware, the only way to increase it is by the user actually doing it via the browser menu.

There might be a way of increasing it programmatically, I don't know, but you would most certainly have to ask the user's permission to do so.

I also think it's a bit much to be expecting someone to allow 10k+ images to be stored on their system, that could be huge.

Comment: I understand that but why is the process stopped when the user is asked to increase the local storage limit ?
Is there an other way to store lot of data offline ?

Comment: I think it stops because there's no more space and it can't add anymore. Since the interaction required from the user is through the browser menu, it's like installing an app on your desktop - once it runs out of diskspace during the installation, it informs you, and then stops. I don't think there's any other way to store so much data offline, and to be honest I think you're expecting too much. No-one would happily allow that much data from a website to be stored on their machine. Why are you trying to store so much?

Comment: This website will be used by our representative so that they could show to their customers our products (we sells young plants and seeds) and maybe take directly their orders.

Comment: Ah, then I guess you'll have to tell all your representatives to change the limit manually beforehand! A bit fiddly I admit, but I'm not sure there's any other way.

Comment: Yes that's why i cannot choose this way ;) i want a good life ;) I think i will try filemaker ;) even if it's more limited ;)